# How to get the procedural interface back?

Tags: php, sqlite

Setting up a new machine, I just discovered the procedural interface to SQLite3 seems to be gone:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sqlite3_open()

Is there any way to get that back again? I tried Google now for a couple of hours, but found no suitable solution so far. If possible, I don't want to rewrite a bunch of code which worked fine until now (changing it may break it ;) -- so any hints as to how to restore that functionality is highly welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write a wrapper, then continue using your old functions.
Example:

```
<?php

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct($filename)
  {
    $this->open($filename);
  }
}

if (!is_defined('sqlite3_open')) {
  function sqlite3_open($filename, $mode = 0666, &$error_message)
  {
    $db = new MyDB($filename);
  } 
}
```